# How to set reference time for SUTime via StanfordNLP server

Tags: stanford-nlp, sutime

I am trying to get sutime annotations using the Stanford CoreNLP server and it seems that the reference time cannot be set using any properties on the server.

Is there a way to do this?

For example, given the text "I need a desk for tomorrow from 2pm to 3pm", I need to provide the reference date as datetime.now() in my Python client for the server in order for SUTime to resolve the word 'tomorrow' to the correct date.

Answer (score 2):

There is, at least in Stanford CoreNLP 3.9.1. Send your text to the following URL:

```
[stanford_server_url]/?properties={"ner.providedDocDate": "yyyy-mm-dd"}
```

I'd wondered about this myself for quite a while. Had to read the source code to find it, though.